# WCF : [XmlElement, typeof] in DataMember attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, serialization

I want to do something like :

```
[XmlElement("Foo1", typeof(Foo1Type))]
[XmlElement("Foo2", typeof(Foo2Type))]
public object Foo { get; set; }
```

I want to do this with the `DataContractSerializer` for WCF.
Something similar in `Datamember` attribute.

This is the equivalent of `xsd:Choice`.

I aim to assign dynamically tags according to their types.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the following MSDN link, the `DataContractSerializer` does not support mapping XSD choice to the CLR equivalent types.

```
choice  |  Forbidden
```

•   **Forbidden**. The DataContractSerializer does not support importing a schema using the feature. For example, Svcutil.exe, when accessing a WSDL with a schema that uses such a feature, falls back to using the XmlSerializer instead. This is by default.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112(v=vs.110).aspx

Note: You may be able to work around the issue using Data Contract Known Types.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Comment: Ok, but this code doesn't work better : `[XmlElement("Foo1", typeof(Foo1Type))]
[XmlElement("Foo2", typeof(Foo2Type))]
[DataMember]
public object Foo { get; set; }` If it falls back to XmlSerializer instead, why my seriazlized XML tag name is always "Foo" and not "Foo1" or "Foo2" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the **ServiceContract** as follows:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="ChoiceService", Namespace="http://dev.janus-net.de/example/choice")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
public interface IChoiceService
```

And add **Serializable** in DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://...", Name = "yourContract")]
[Serializable]
```

The complet example are in: http://www.janus-net.de/2007/08/07/using-xschoice-in-wcf-services/